# Fetching data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table 1 with columns

- `userid`
- `deptname`
- `deptid`
- `working_in`
- `joining_date`
- `profession`

Table 2 has columns

- `userid`
- `salary`
- `doj`
- `user_mail`

And table 3 contains

- `userid`
- `deptname`
- `deptid`
- `salary`

Both Table 1 and Table 2 contain some rows. Table 3 contains no rows.

The values of table 3 will be the combination of values from table 1 and table 2.

How do I update table 3 by fetching only the details `userid`, `deptname`, `deptid`, `salary` required from table 1 and table 2?

Comment: What do you mean by "... the combination of values ..." ?

Comment: I have tried the sql codes mentioned below , but I'm not getting my desired result.

Comment: Then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33859029/edit) your question and enhance its text with a sample of your data and the expected output based on the sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.userid, t1.deptname, t1.deptid, t2.salary from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.userid=t2.userid
```

That way you can, in a single query, get the details from both tables. Notice that I used the a join according to the "userid" column. That way the "salary" will be of the same user (assuming "userid" is a shared PK).

**EDIT:**
In the example code above you don't insert anything. There is only a SELECT statement. That means, you're only extracting the relevant data from both table1 and table2. In order to put the data inside of table3 you need an INSERT stetment. You can look it up here http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php , And it should end up something like :

```
INSERT INTO table3 
(userid, deptname, deptid, salary)
VALUES (select t1.userid, t1.deptname, t1.deptid, t2.salary from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.userid=t2.userid)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I have tried the code that you mentioned and it still doesn't work. Is Join used for creating new columns from the other tables along with the values or It is used to update only the values in the existing table? The table 3 that I mentioned doesn't contain any values. I wanted selected column's data's present in table 1 and table 2 to be updated in table 3. Also does the sql code that you mentioned end with a semi-colon? I am very new to pl/sql.

Comment: `insert ... VALUES (select ...)` is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

1. your "Table 1" is named `table_1`,
2. your "Table 2" is named `table_2`,
3. your "Table 3" is named `table_3`,
4. your "combination of values" is a join between table 1 and table 2 on the `userid` column, and
5. your "I update table 3" means you want to store the "combination of values" into your table 3,

then your query would be:

```
insert into table_3 (userid, deptname, deptid, salary)
select userid, T1.deptname, T1.deptid, T2.salary
from table_1 T1
    join table_2 T2 using (userid)
;
```